# Excel - Multiple subsets of data on one line graph

Tags: excel, linegraph

I'm trying make a line graph that has multiple lines on it, each representing a question number and its data. I cannot get it to display properly. My data is structured like this...

```
Question Precision      Time
0        30.49849888    2000
0        31.44534664    3000
0        16.87857557    4000
0        48.49384985    5000
1        30.49849888    2000
1        31.44534664    3000
1        16.87857557    4000
1        48.49384985    5000
```

The data goes up to 5 questions. How can I create a single line graph in Excel that has separate lines for each question?

I plan to use `time` on the x axis and `precision` on the y.

Comment: Could you please be more specific: what would you like to have as X and what is Y axis, and how would you like to define data series? Regards,

Comment: x and y info is at the end of the question, and I'm not sure what you mean by defining a data series, sorry.

Comment: Data Series regarding Excel charting is essentially the line made on the collection of data points (specified by X and Y values). In your case it seems you would have a single line (data series) connecting 8 data points; so what is the problem?

Comment: I would like each question (numbered 0-4) to have their own line, so the graph would have 5 separate lines, each line corresponding to each questions data (precision and time). Does that make sense?

Comment: Like this: http://support.sas.com/kb/42/addl/fusion_42069_4_42069_needed_line.jpg where `Product` would be `Question number`, `Total inventory` would be `Precision` and `Region` would be `Time`

Comment: So, I guess there are more data rows that you did not show, containing data points for Q 2, Q3, Q4. In this case, you will have 4 data series. It's quite simple.

Comment: That is correct, the list is very long so I didn't want to show it all. It may be simple, but I'm not sure how to actually do it in Excel

Comment: To be more clear, I'm not sure how I can make Excel realise the data is in subsets (each question)

Comment: Please see the answer below. Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple way to achieve your goal is:

1. Create a chart with single data series for Q1

   2. Right-click on the chart, select "Select Data..." option and then Add Series for another
      data range (Q2)

3). Repeat this for the rest.

Regards

Comment: Sure, you are welcome. Best of luck with your project. Regds,